# xnor schematic problem with supply ports

Tags: power-supply, cadence

I have a problem with my circuit. i am new at electronics and i have an essay to implement an XNOR gate with cadence program.
I have a XNOR gate and i don't know where the voltage input and ground should be connected. Can anyone help me? My concern is that i don't know where to connect it with out changing the functionality of the circuit

[image]

Answer (score -2):

i found the answer ! the vss supply must connect with nmos bulk and the vdd with the pmos bulk